# How do I keep an object's "perceived" rotation consistent in three.js?

Tags: 3d, three.js, rotation, image-rotation, aframe

I have a part programming / part math question: I have a bunch of draggable planes in a three.js environment. The camera is in the middle of a sphere and can rotate but can't change position. The planes drag along the sphere and keep their global rotation (if you console.log(plane.rotation), it will be the same as you drag it along the sphere). However at a certain point, it "disappears". I imagine it's kind of like a piece of paper - if you were to rotate around the piece of paper, at a certain point as you're rotating around it, it would like like it "disappeared", when you only see the edge of the paper. Basically, I would like to manually set the rotation of the object so that it maintains it's visual rotation, which would have to account for the position on the sphere and the camera's rotation I think? I have tried using "lookAt", but that just has the object look at the camera directly and sometimes, the plane will have a slight rotation (the plane will not always be looking at the camera). I have attached a few photos to explain more what I'm talking about:

[This is the image of the plane pre-dragging.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjeJo.png)

[This is the image of the plane post-dragging. As you can see, the plane is now just a line, appears to "disappear".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb3ie.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated! I believe I have to do something with quaternions and normals, but I don't even know how to approach this problem and I've been working on it for quite a while now!

Comment: Does this need the `aframe` tag?

Comment: No... But I encountered the same problem when using A-frame, so I thought that people using A-frame would benefit from the answers...

Comment: Using a `THREE.Group` to wrap all planes and your sphere?

Comment: Are you sure you want the planes to -maintain- their relative orientation, in stead of -facing- the camera? Wouldn't that look really unfamiliar and impractical, e.g. for the two planes on the left and right sides of the first image?

Comment: @Paul-Jan Yeah, I'm positive. I'm making a software so I want to make sure that users have the ability to change the object's rotation but still be able to drag the object without having to re-change the object's rotation.

Comment: @Craig.Li I tried that and that didn't work either :( Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @sue Roh I still think you can do this with `THREE.Group()`, If you want every plane keep a special orientation, just set rotation to the plane, and attach the plane to a three-group, you just need to make the three-group lookAt camera wherever you translate the plane, the plane will keep a special orientation.